# log4j2 not writing to both Console and File

Tags: log4j2

I am new to log4j2.  I created a very simple java project in eclipse to try it out.

log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" >
  <Properties>
    <Property name="test">test</Property>
  </Properties>
  <ThresholdFilter/>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <File name="LogFile" fileName="test.log">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%t %-5p %c{2} - %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </File>
  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <Root level="ERROR">
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
    </Root>
    <Logger name="tutorial" level="TRACE">
      <Appender-Ref ref="STDOUT" />
      <Appender-Ref ref="LogFile" />
    </Logger>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Test.java

```
package tutorial;

public class Test {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Test.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(logger.getName());
        logger.info("*****Testing*****");
        logger.log(Level.WARN, "*****Testing*****");
    }
}
```

Result of running Test.java

```
tutorial.Test
```

There were no logging from log4j at all both in console and log file.  The log file, test.log, is created but there's noting in it.  Can any one with expertise help decipher the mystery?

JDK: jdk1.8.0_92 
log4j2: 2.6.2

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I generally don't use xml to configure my log4j, but it looks like your log level is set to Error so your logger.info won't print.

Comment: Hi @scrappedcola, Thanks for your quick response.  Even with the root logger level changed to TRACE, I am still not getting the log output from log4j.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause of threshold filter log4j log is not displayed.

If it is not required then can you try with removing below line.

```
<ThresholdFilter/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Nikunj Shekhada.  Somehow, I missed that tag and was pulling my hairs..